# Are there alternatives to MCR-ALS for determining pure response profiles of a mixture?

Tags: data-mining, software

MCR-ALS says it is a tool for "the recovery of the pure response profiles of the chemical constituents or species of an unresolved mixture when no prior information is available about the nature and composition of these mixtures."  Glotaran/TIMP also offer singular value decomposition.  Are there other tools I could consider using for similar purposes?

I am particularly interested in comparing the tolerance of tools to missing data and the quality of the documentation.

Comment: I thought this question was too specialised for software recommendations stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the Matlab [N-way toolbox](http://www.models.life.ku.dk/nwaytoolbox) by Rasmus Bro et al or the commercial version, the [PLS Toolbox by Eigenvector Research](http://www.eigenvector.com/software/pls_toolbox.htm), [NMFLab or NTFLab](http://www.bsp.brain.riken.jp/ICALAB/nmflab.html) for Matlab, [MVC2](http://www.iquir-conicet.gov.ar/descargas/mvc2.rar) or [MVC3](http://www.iquir-conicet.gov.ar/descargas/mvc3.rar), or the [osd](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/osd/index.html),  [ALS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ALS/index.html), [NMF](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NMF/index.html), [multiway](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multiway/index.html) or [metaMS](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/metaMS.html) packages in R. I've tried most of these for separating coeluting compounds in GC/MS chromatograms but wasn't all that impressed by any of them unfortunately - most need quite a lot of tinkering to make them work, and imposing a sufficient number of constraints is really critical to get good results (e.g. nonnegativity, unimodal peak shapes, good initial estimates, correct estimation of chemical rank/correct nr of peaks etc) - and most are not robust enough yet for routine research. But it can be done! I was just working on a modified MCR-ALS algorithm that uses elastic net regularization to enforce sparseness plus unimodality and nonnegativity constraints that seems to perform reasonably well... 
Good reviews are Cichocki et al.'s book "[Nonnegative matrix and tensor factorizations: applications to explanatory multi-way data analysis and blind source separation](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470746661.html)" and the "[Handbook of Blind Source separation: Independent Component Analysis and Applications](https://www.google.be/imgres?imgurl=http://t0.gstatic.com/images%3Fq%3Dtbn:ANd9GcSiBx7TR7YGJ1YZJCKANxeyxvvxwhDNDh71cu9cMyS7DInuHSnH&imgrefurl=http://books.google.com/books/about/Handbook_of_Blind_Source_Separation.html%3Fid%3DPTbj03bYH6kC%26source%3Dkp_cover&h=780&w=600&tbnid=0Fim59PuLsaKlM:&vet=1&tbnh=160&tbnw=123&docid=gcY8ido7iCDuVM&itg=1&client=firefox-b&usg=__Uj6Q2JgZ2Y4mgF7DhLmv-6QcDJo=&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiiorvmhrnSAhVBNxQKHZayAZ4Q_B0IogEwFA#h=780&imgrc=0Fim59PuLsaKlM:&tbnh=160&tbnw=123&vet=1&w=600)". There is also lots of software for specific applications, e.g. for GC/MS data the free program AMDIS, or the commercial ChromaTOF or Scanalytics Analyzer Pro.

Comment: Which one do you like best?  Especially with respect to tolerance of missing data and documentation?

Comment: Well my final take was that to get good results you really need to take into account as much problem-specific knowledge (e.g. about expected peak shapes, constraints, etc) as possible and that all or most of the programs above don't do this out of the box (except AMDIS, ChromaTOF and Analyzer Pro, which are very problem-specific but also have problems of their own). The NLS Toolbox, osd and als worked a bit better for the problems I'm working with, but none were perfect. Which is why in the end I now decided to develop something of my own... Most require preprocessing to handle missing data.